# Basic React code not producing any output on my PC

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

A simple react code is not working on my PC.

The HTML file is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>React Intro</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="root">

    </div>
    <script src="./App.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The React file is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

ReactDOM.render( <h1>Hello</h1> ,document.getElementById("root"))
```

When I run the HTML file using the live server nothing is displayed. Whereas "Hello" should have been displayed.

Comment: you need to add React and ReactDOM in your html file as a `script`

Comment: Refer: https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html
Also checkout about babel

Comment: Your `div` has a class called `root` no id. Changing `<div class="root">` to `<div id="root">` should to the trick

Comment: you need to _bundle_ your code with the React libraries. See https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/learn-webpack-for-react-a36d4cac5060/

Answer (score 2):

## Getting React to run

Web browsers do not support:

- `import` unless:

  - you explicitly declare the script to be a module with the `type` attribute
  - you use URLs as the value you are importing from (and not module names like node.js)
- JSX

---

**You need to convert your JSX + modules into JS that the browser supports.**

The best way to do this is with a toolchain as described [in the React documentation](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#setup-option-2-local-development-environment).

(I strongly recommend taking Option 2 and using Node.js + a bundler. Option 1 (client-side Babel) has some shortcomings (such as lack of convenient support for modules).

- Make sure you have a recent version of Node.js installed.
- Run `npx create-react-app my-app`
- `cd my-app`
- `npm run start`

---

Other options are available, such as [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/recipes.html#react) (which is simpler but less commonly used and thus there is less help out there) and [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/create-nextjs-app?utm_source=next-site&utm_medium=homepage-cta&utm_campaign=next-website) (which is more complicated but bakes in server-side rendering).

---

## Your typo

You have also said `<div class="root">` and then tried to access it with `getElementById`. Give it an id, not a class.

---

Aside: Do learn to use the developer tools in your browser. There would have been error messages in the Console that you should have quoted in the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Using npx create-react-app my-app and editing the App.js worked.